# How should I serialize a vb.NET object which has class attributes with JsonConvert?

Tags: vb.net, serialization, json.net

I am trying to use Json.NET to serialize an object in vb.NET.

The object fails to serialize correctly.  This seems to be because of some attributes on the class.
Below is the class definition – a very simple definition.

Here is the code to serialize:

```
Dim MyObject As New TestClass() With {.Property1 = "Hello", .Property2 = 3}
Dim Serialized As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MyObject)
```

After the 2 lines above execute, the variable **Serialized** has the following value (which is not what I would expect or want):

```
"Namespace1.TestClass"
```

When I remove the class attributes completely (just the class attributes, not the property attributes) and then execute the same 2 lines of code, the variable **Serialized** has the following value (which is what I would expect):

```
{"Property1":"Hello","Property2":"3"}
```

This is only an example: we have many such classes with these kinds of attributes.  We need to serialize them with Json.NET.
Removing the attributes is not possible, the classes I am dealing with are part of a system of existing applications and WCF based web services (i.e. part of our system needs our current serialization system for WCF kept in place, and another part of our system needs to serialize the same class with Json .. I won't go into the "why" details, just that we are serializing thousands of such objects for database writes and have speed and space isues).

I realize also that I can use JsonTextWriter to serialize, but then we have maintenance issues – every time we add/remove a property we have to remember to maintain the serialization code appropriately.

So how must I serialize this class correctly without removing the attributes?

I have not seen anything on the NewtonSoft site, nor anywhere else, which addresses this specific problem.

Here again is the class definition, along with the attributes.

```
<System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute  ("System.Xml", "2.0.50727.3053"), _  
 System.SerializableAttribute(), _  
 System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute(), _  
 System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code"), _  
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute  ([Namespace]:="http://Namespace.com/SomePath/SomeXsd.xsd",   TypeName:="TestClass"), _  
 System.ComponentModel.TypeConverterAttribute(GetType  (System.ComponentModel.ExpandableObjectConverter))> _  
Partial Public Class TestClass

    Private _Property1 As String
    Private _Property2 As Integer


    <System.ComponentModel.Browsable(False), System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()> _
    Public Property Property1() As String
        Get
            Return Me._Property1
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            If (Me._Property1 <> value) Then
                Me._Property1 = value
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    <System.ComponentModel.Browsable(False), System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()> _
    Public Property Property2() As String
        Get
            Return Me._Property2
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            If (Me._Property2 <> value) Then
                Me._Property2 = value
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

Comment: Any feedback with the answers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `TypeConverterAttribute` on your class.  When Json.Net sees that, it will use the associated `TypeConverter` to convert the object to a string.  In this case, it results in the class's type name being output.

You can override the unwanted behavior by adding a `JsonObjectAttribute` to the classes that have a `TypeConverterAttribute` applied.  But since it appears that your classes are generated code, it might not be feasible to do that on an class-by-class basis unless you can modify the code generator.  In that case, another alternative is to use a custom [`IContractResolver`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_IContractResolver.htm) to force Json.Net to ignore the `TypeConverter` on classes that have it.

Here is the code you would need for the resolver:

```
Class TypeConverterIgnoringResolver
    Inherits DefaultContractResolver

    Protected Overrides Function CreateContract(objectType As Type) As JsonContract
        If objectType.GetCustomAttributes(True) _
                     .OfType(Of System.ComponentModel.TypeConverterAttribute)() _
                     .Any() _
        Then
            Return MyBase.CreateObjectContract(objectType)
        End If
        Return MyBase.CreateContract(objectType)
    End Function

End Class
```

You can use the resolver like this:

```
Dim MyObject As New TestClass() With {.Property1 = "Hello", .Property2 = 3}
Dim Settings As New JsonSerializerSettings
Settings.ContractResolver = New TypeConverterIgnoringResolver()
Dim Serialized As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MyObject, Settings)
Console.WriteLine(Serialized)
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/s6Ebmc

Comment: Brian, thank you for your quick response! I tried this out and it worked perfectly with our code.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you don't want to change your `TestClass` as it must have been generated by some tool, I would suggest to derive a new class from it:

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json

<JsonObject()>
Public Class OtherClass
    Inherits TestClass

End Class
```

and use the attribute `<JsonObject()>`. This should do the trick:

```
Dim MyObject As New OtherClass() With {.Property1 = "Hello", .Property2 = 3}
Dim Serialized As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MyObject)
```

UPDATE:

Since you're already working with a Partial you can extend it creating a new one (in another folder):

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json

<JsonObject()>
Partial Public Class TestClass

End Class
```

Comment: LeftyX, thank you for the answer.  I will keep this in mind - it may be helpful later on as we continue to work with Json serialization.
For now, we don't want to create and maintain new objects, so we are going to use the custom IContractResolver.